# How can i solve the red warnings in flutter when i start to to run

Tags: flutter, dart

i have everything up to date in `flutter` and `dart`.
and i have no issues when i run `flutter doctor` . everything sound good

but i still get these red warnings lines when i start to debug

```
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-3.1.11\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-9.1.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\analytics\FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_analytics-9.1.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\analytics\FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.3.12\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-9.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\database\FirebaseDatabasePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:205: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:217: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:226: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:239: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:249: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:259: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:285: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:295: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:312: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:331: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:352: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:372: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:388: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:411: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:434: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:584: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(cachedThreadPool, HashMap::new);
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:589: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStorageTask.java:169: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStorageTask.java:186: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-10.2.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStorageTask.java:203: warning: [deprecation] <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>) in Tasks has been deprecated
    return Tasks.call(
                ^
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>call(Executor,Callable<TResult>)
20 warnings
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_native_image-0.0.6+1\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutternativeimage\FlutterNativeImagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.1.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.12\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

please How can i solve this , it's so annoying

Comment: do flutter clean, flutter pub upgrade and flutter pub get and run again

Comment: You probably can't, Firebase plugins are, as you can see, plugins, you have no control over the source-code, although you can work for the plugin on the original repository and fix these errors

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your Firebase plugins are up to date and in sync and are the correct version in pubspec.yaml. Rerun the flutter clean commands After doing so to make sure everything is refreshed.

Comment: All  done . still waning showing

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by upgrading to this version of firebase:

```
firebase_core: ^1.15.0
firebase_auth: ^3.3.16
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13
firebase_storage: ^10.2.14
```